# How to put messageBottomLabel inside of message bubble?

Tags: swift, messagekit

I am using messageKit. I want to add time when the message was sent inside of messageBottomLabel. However visually it is outside of message bubble.

[image]

But I want it to be inside of the bubble, like this:

[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to hide the default bottom label. (MessagesLayoutDelegate)
2. Make a custom cell for each kind of message you want to change.
3. Register cell
4. Change the function below to use the custom cell.

> func customCell(for message: MessageType,
> at indexPath: IndexPath,
> in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> UICollectionViewCell

5. Add a label to the content view of the cell.
6. At cell configuration

> func configure(with message: MessageType, at indexPath:
> IndexPath, and messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView)

set label text like this:

> ```
>     if let dataSource = messagesCollectionView.messagesDataSource {
>         captionLabel.text = dataSource.messageBottomLabelAttributedText(for: message, at: indexPath)
>     } else { fatalError("Datasource is null!") }
> ```

7. Then, you have to calculate the height of the cell at

> override func messageContainerSize(for message: MessageType) ->
> CGSize